# Non-admin user facing issue while accessing Sitecore items

Tags: sitecore-client, security, role-management

We are getting below error while login as non-admin user and accessing the Sitecore items

> "The security settings for the current language prevent you from
>   seeing this item. To continue, select another language from the
>   Language drop-down list on the Versions tab."

I have check the below post and language `read/write` access already there to the user 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243493/sitecore-cant-access-content-items

This works fine, only when I recycle app pool. But reoccurring again and again in every week or 2 differences.

Any permanent solution for this? I am using Sitecore 8.1 Update 3.

Comment: Every 2-3 weeks...  Are you sure these language items are not deployed as part of your integration processes?  If /sitecore/system/languages is under TDS or Unicorn control in your environment, any changes to security settings on these would get overwritten. And it happening every 2-3 weeks would seem to indicate something like this.

Comment: Hi Mark,
Yes language item not deployed.it's stable system only file system deployment happening.

Comment: Is this item in some workflow. Check if this item is given rights to the workflow entities in the security editor. Please post a screen shot on the access viewer including these two columns as well. Regards,
Gopi.S.V

Comment: No it is not in workflow.it is occurs for every item when issue reproduces.Can't see any option to attache or paste screenshot here.

Comment: You can't attach screenshot in a comment but attach with your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have followed all steps given in the link then, sitecore stores all security access details to individual item's _security field under standard field. Please check this field values whenever you face the same issue again and if you don't find language read/write access there then there must be something which overwrite you language item, it could be package or could be some mistake in deployment which overwrites your language items.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after upgrade to Sitecore 10
at the beginning I was cleaning cache every now and then but the issue was coming back randomly then I found permanent solution below:
go to control panel-> Administration tools-> Database Cleanup-> Cleanup Invalid Language Data